# find similar records with multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 100k records in a dataframe

[image]

and want to find out different prices for the same product for the same invoice and different invoices
along with the store. data snippet of the data mentioned

expected output

[image]

Comment: what is pcode? how to determine the "same product" from the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group a dataframe by multiple columns.

Let's create your DataFrame first:

```
import pandas as pd 
   
InvoiceNo = pd.Series(data=["c123","q321","w345", "c123", "c123", "c123", "w345", "q321", "t654", "t654", "t658"])
    StoreCode = pd.Series(data=[101,245,215,101,101,101,215,245,101,245,389])
    price = pd.Series(data=[1000,2000,3000,1500,2500,2500,3500,2500,1700,1900,3500])
    pcode = pd.Series(data=[7890,5670,4560,7890,7890,7890,4560,
                            5670,8367,8367,9595])
    
InvoiceNo.name = 'InvoiceNo'
StoreCode.name= 'StoreCode'
price.name= 'price'
pcode.name="pcode"
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(InvoiceNo),pd.DataFrame(StoreCode),pd.DataFrame(price),pd.DataFrame(pcode)], axis=1)
```

Mask for the criteria (although this is not necessary for the example snippet given)

```
mask_invoice = df['InvoiceNo'].duplicated(keep=False)
mask_store = df["StoreCode"].duplicated(keep=False)
mask_pcode = df["pcode"].duplicated(keep=False)
df_masked = df[mask_pcode & mask_store & mask_invoice]
```

Now we have dropped the single entries by pcode, StoreCode and InvoiceNo.

```
  InvoiceNo StoreCode price pcode
0   c123     101    1000    7890
1   q321     245    2000    5670
2   w345     215    3000    4560
3   c123     101    1500    7890
4   c123     101    2500    7890
5   c123     101    2500    7890
6   w345     215    3500    4560
7   q321     245    2500    5670
8   t654     101    1700    8367
9   t654     245    1900    8367
```

Grouping the dataframe with multiple columns:

```
dfg = df_masked.groupby(by=["StoreCode", "InvoiceNo"])

df_output = pd.DataFrame()
for group, data in dfg:
  data.drop_duplicates(subset=["InvoiceNo", "StoreCode", "price"] ,inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
  if len(data) >1:
    df_output = pd.concat([df_output, data], ignore_index=True)
```

data.drop_duplicates eliminates duplicate rows within the grouped data - "c123" with price 2500 in this case.

Final output:

```
>>print(df_output)

InvoiceNo StoreCode price pcode
0   c123     101    1000    7890
1   c123     101    1500    7890
2   c123     101    2500    7890
3   w345     215    3000    4560
4   w345     215    3500    4560
5   q321     245    2000    5670
6   q321     245    2500    5670
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how to determine if products are the same, however you can use this code and change the subset values in order to keep only unique rows in the dataframe:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['InvoiceCo', 'pcode', 'price'], keep="last").sort_values(by=['StoreCode'])
```

Comment: please accept and upvote if it helped